# How many syllables in this mantra?

Tags: mantras, narayan

I am trying to understand if we count Om and Namah when calculating the number of syllables in a mantra , like the following:

> Om Shree Narayanayah namah

What does the books say?

Comment: When say shiva panchakshar mantra , we don't count om, we count namah. 

Namah = 2 Shivaya = 3. So total 5. In case of  Shree(1) Narayanayah(4) namah(2).
So total 7. I am may be wrong just drawing parallels.

Comment: makes sense, shouldnt we count Na-ra-ya-na-ya = 5 instead of 4 ?

Comment: Not sure with my very limited knowledge, I know Na-ra-ya-na